# How to implement lazy load for an SVG image element?

Tags: javascript, image, svg, onload

Within an svg tag, there multiple image elements, showing thumbnail images. Because of the large number of images, the page loading tooks a long time. So I want to implement an easy lazy load like [David Walsh’s Simple Image Lazy Load and Fade](https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/). For img elements it works fine. But for image elements of an SVG area, the load will not be done.
Example:

```
<div>
    <img id="myimg" height="20" width="20" data-src="img1.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>
    <svg width="10%">
    <image id="myimage" height="20" width="20" xlink:href="img1.jpg"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

And the JS coding:

```
// This works fine
var img = jQuery("#myimg");
img.attr('src', img.attr('data-src'));
img.on("load", function () {
    img.removeAttr('data-src');
});

// This doens't work, onload will not be processed, image will not be not shown
var image = jQuery("#myimage");
image.attr('xlink:href', image.attr('data-href'));
image.on("load", function () {
    image.removeAttr('data-href');
});
```

The scripting will leave the page in this way:

```
<div>
    <img id="myimg" height="20" width="20" data-src="img1.jpg"/>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <svg width="10%">
    <image id="myimage" height="20" width="20" data-href="img1.jpg" xlink:href="img1.jpg"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Why is onload not working for this SVG image element?

Comment: What gives you the idea that an `<image>` element inside a `<svg>` element has an `onload` event?

Comment: I found onload as one the graphical event attributes for the image element, definded in the SVG Document Structure Specification 1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several small mistakes:
`<image/>` is a self-closing tag,
`xlink:href` should be used without `xlink:` prefix,
it's better to set eventListener **before** you changing attribute.

See the snippet:

```js
var image = jQuery("#myimage");
image.on("load", function () {
    console.log('loaded');
    image.removeAttr('data-href');
});
image.attr('href', image.attr('data-href'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
    <image id="myimage" width="150" height="150" data-href="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/843090368837042176/Nl-rCb9c_400x400.jpg"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I did it in FF 58.0.2. What is your FF version?

Comment: Same. Hmm. It works when opening a separate file, but from an iframe, no request goes out. Can you see it from this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQdbLG)?

Comment: The codepen works well. Probably you have adblocker on?

Comment: Already checked. This admittedly was the issue at first, but the rule is now removed. I have packed the snippet in a separate file and it works with the file:// protocol, but not from a local server. Whatever it is, it seems to be a local browser config issue, so not related to this question,

Comment: Works in Chromium 64.0 an FF 58.0.2.
But why do I have to use href instead of xlink:href?

Comment: `xlink` is used within Xlink namespace of XML document, which is not applicable in our example. Also [read this](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/linking.html#XLinkRefAttrs)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the same problem where I keep using the xlink:href attribute for the raster image to show inside the SVG, but still lazy-load on click.  I'm using different lazy-load plugin (jquery.lazy.js) but it's very similar:

```
<svg>
    <image id="lazy-img" class="lazy" width="" height="" data-source="myimage.jpg" />
</svg>

$('.someElement').on('click', function() {
    var image = $('#lazy-img");
    image.attr('xlink:href', 'myimage.jpg');
    image.attr('href', 'myimage.jpg');
 });
```

The idea is that the initial HTML markup is for the lazy-loading images and on click event we are swapping the markup back to work with SVG, after the image is lazy-loaded.